# Formatting a receipt on a thermal epson TM-T20II printer

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

Am trying to format a receipt to a thermal printer. The printer can only align to one side at a time. using ESC/POS commands to reset and print to another alignment makes it print slowly and also loses the previous line it was supposed to print.
Is there a way i can format the receipt before sending it to the printer? I would really appreciate any help.

This is my code:

```
private void btnPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();
    System.out.println(printerService.getPrinters());
    byte[] left = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x61, 0x00};
    byte[] center = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x61, 0x01};
    byte[] right = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x61, 0x02};
    byte[] reset = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40};
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", center);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II", 
            "\n\n PUMP FITNESS LIMITED"
            + "\n Address : 52763 NAIROBI"
            + "\n Tel : 0714183897"
            + "\n***********************************************"
            + "\n CASH SALE [ORIGINAL]");
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II","\n++");
    printerServiceprintBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", reset);
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", left);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II","\n RCT No.: " + sTrID);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II","++");
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", reset);
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", right);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II",
            "Date : " + sTrDt + "\n Time : " + sTrTm);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II","\n++");
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", reset);
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", left);
    printerService.printString("EPSON TM-T20II", 
            "\n Client No.: " + sID
            + "\n Received from : " + sClNm
            + "\n DESCRIPTION            QTY           AMT(Ksh)"
            + "\n***********************************************"
            + "\n " + sPSNm + "" + sQty + "" +  sPSPrice
            + "\n Discount" + sDisc
            + "\n***********************************************"
            + "\n Total" + sNAmt
            + "\n Tendered Amount" + sCash
            + "\n Change" + sBal
            + "\n***********************************************"
            + "\n Pmt Mode : " + sPmtMode + "Cash Pnt:" + sCPNm
            + "\n Cashier : " + sUNm + "Shift No.: " + sShiftNo
            + "\n Powered By Pump Fitness Ltd."
            + "\n\n\n\n\n");
    // cut that paper!
    byte[] cutP = new byte[] { 0x1d, 'V', 1 };
    printerService.printBytes("EPSON TM-T20II", cutP);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printing is slow because you are sendind commands "byte by byte".
Just use a ByteArrayOutputStream, "print" everything in it. 
When done, send it to your printerServicen, oneshot.

Comment: The printing is slow because you are sendind commands "byte by byte". Just use a ByteArrayOutputStream, "print" everything in it. When done, send it to your printerServicen, oneshot. 



Thanks BluEOS, The ByteArrayOutputStream improved the speed but I still cannot align one string to the right and the other to the left on the same line.
Is there a work around for this?

Comment: All you need is already done in OpenConcerto : see /trunk/OpenConcerto/src/org/openconcerto/erp/core/sales/pos/io/DefaultTicketPrinter.java  from https://code.openconcerto.org